# Native Languages converting to Bold L and Dots while viewing in Adobe

Tags: adobe, acrobat, reader

The pdf is filled with Telugu Language and while viewing the pdf in Adobe, it opens the form properly and then change field data to gibberish after 2-3 seconds. If you copy that data and paste in notepad or any text editor, the data is proper. Even if you open the pdf with any other pdf viewer like Chrome, Foxit etc, the data is still proper. Can anybody help me out why this happens only in Adobe and how to fix it?

File is in this path: https://gofile.io/?c=AFKX6T